# How do I change pattern from one array to another and then back

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have an original array in C++ that could be containing any numbers and change in length, but this is my example with the following simple content:

```
{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

What I want is to change the order of the array
By splitting the array up in blocks of dynamic size like, let us say 3 (could be something else in size).

```
int len = 10;
int blocks = 10/3;
```

And use these values to split the array up in blocks about 3 numbers:

```
0,1,2 | 3,4,5 | 6,7,8 | 9
```

And then take the first value from first block and next value from the next block like:

```
0,3, 1,4, 2,5,
```

And then jump two blocks and add next part like:

```
6,9, 7, 8
```

7 and 8 will be alone since there are no more parts in the last block for these two numbers.
The complete result should then be like:

```
0,3,1,4,2,5,6,9,7,8
```

How could I solve this problem with an algorithm when the last block might sometimes not contain a complete set of numbers?

And how could I after that create an algorithm to reverse the result array back to what it was?

And no this isn't an assignment, I'm going to use it to shuffle a soundfile around to make it hard for others to just copy the file and use it however they want.

EDIT: Here is my last test attempt that I got stuck on:

```
static int test[] = { 0 ,1 ,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
static int testTo[] = { -1 ,-1 ,-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int len = 10;
    int block = len/3.0;
    for (int i=0;i<len;i=i+block*2)
    {
        for (int y=0;y<block&&i+(y*2)+1<len-1;y++)
        {
            testTo[i+(y*2)] = test[i+y];
            testTo[i+(y*2)+1] = test[(i+block)+y];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have code that can handle arrays where the last block is the correct length? Then we could help you modify that instead of writing the whole thing or vaguely describing strategies for handling it without real code to refer to.

Comment: I have no idea how to answer this without just giving you the code, which I don't feel would help you a whole lot in the long run, or be particularly appropriate for the same reason, because the code seems to flow pretty logically from the described pattern. Have you tried writing the code yourself?

Comment: Yes, I have. I have working on it for about a week now and couldn't make it out. Getting lost on how to do the last block!

Comment: I'll add my last test code then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix would be to separating out the `testTo` counter, which makes us not have to worry about complicated code to work with the end of the array - we can happily generate out of bounds indices, then simply ignore them by checking if we've gone out of bounds.

I also thought I'd simplify your code a little.

This is what I came up with:

```
int test[] = { 0 ,1 ,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int testTo[] = { -1 ,-1 ,-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};
int len = 10;
int block = len/3.0;
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i = i + block*2)
   for (int y = 0; y < block; y++)
      for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++) // made this a loop rather than 2 statements
      {
         int index = i + y + z*block;
         if (index < len)
            testTo[counter++] = test[index];
      }
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/TBJHuY).

---

The end of the array poses quite a bit more of a problem when trying to convert the data back.

Would it be possible to just pad the last pairs of blocks with some unused value (say 0)? So we'd get:

```
0,1,2 | 3,4,5 | 6,7,8 | 9,0,0
```

Which would give us an output of:

```
0,3,1,4,2,5,6,9,7,0,8,0
```

Which would be much easier to convert back.

Alternatively, if you're stuck with your structure, or feel like braving the code anyway:

When dealing with the last pairs of blocks, you could base what you need to do on the number of elements remaining in the array. Take note of the fact that we have 4 elements (`6,9,7,8`) in our last pairs of blocks, now also note that the data is in the form `firstBlock secondBlock firstBlock firstBlock` - we alternate between the blocks once, then run out of elements in the second block, so just pick from the first block. More generally, the number of times we alternate (and thus the number of items in the second block) is `elementsRemaining - blockSize`, which is `4-3=1` in this case.

Comment: Thanks Dukeling, this was making my brain work again.